Why is the column name's alias in lowercase and not the expected one?
On the staging, I am working with PHP 7 on the Yii2 framework, where I have a connection with MySQL 8 database.
On the production, the code is run on PHP 5.6 with the same Yii2 framework, where I have a connection with MySQL 8 database.
I have the following code which is a query in one of the API:
$cartItems = $cart->getItems()->select(['id', 'product_id as productId'])->andWhere(['product_id' => $productIds])->asArray()->all();
foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem) {
            $productDetail = $body[$cartItem['productId']];    // ⬅️ Undefined Index Error Here
            ...
}

In the production everything is fine.
In the staging, I faced an issue where the $cartItems was throwing Undefined index: productId, as shown in the snippet. When I printed the variable using die(print_r($cartItems));, I got the following data:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [productid] => 456
        )

)

Ideally, the data shouldn't have productid but instead productId as key. And because of that the code is breaking in the next step.
I tried one solution that ChatGPT suggested but it didn't help and I got the same data.
use yii\db\Expression; // Import used for the Expression


$cartItems = $cart->getActiveItems()->select(['id', new Expression('product_id as productId')])->andWhere(['product_id' => $parentProductIds])->asArray()->all();


This behavior caused by setting PDO::CASE_LOWER in your DB connection settings

The best is to have almost the same environment of staging and production. If that not possible, then you could maybe try to lowercase your keys, where is needed?
There is the array_change_key_case function in php. Because is 2 dimensions table, make sure to apply them in the inline ones.

Ideally, but this comes under one of the old codes left untouched in our system. When I started the testing for one of my features, the issue came up on the staging.
